# How to navigate in a Xamarin.Forms application as a specific user

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

My mobile application has a login page, and i want to do some thing like that:
when a user login he can navigate in all pages with his id, so he see his réservations, he can make a new reservation, he can cancel a reservation... (like sessions in a web application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store user id to local storage then navigate pages with this user id

To store id in local storeage you can use application.current.properties:

```
Application.Current.Properties ["id"] = userId;
App.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
```

And to get id from local storage:

```
if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("id"))
{
    var id = Application.Current.Properties ["id"] as int;
}
```

Comment: Please note that is the Xamarin Forms way of doing things. With Prism 6.3 you should be using `IApplicationStore` this exposes the Application Properties and SaveProperties methods while keeping your code testable.

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin.Forms you can navigate to the specific page like this:

```
 await Navigation.PushAsync(new YourSpecificPage
        {
            BindingContext = the view model of your navigating page

        });
```

OR, you can create your page object and can navigate towards it as :

```
var newPage = newPage();
await Navigation.PushAsync(newPage);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chiranjhivi Ghimire, my question was to navigate as a specific user not to a specific page. i'm sorry may be my question was not clear.